# LinuxPerfAsmProfiler shows Java code corresponding assembly hot spot for Java 8, but not for Java 14

Tags: java, performance, assembly, jvm, profiling

When investigating an issue related to instantiation of Spring's `org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap` (as of `spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE`) I've used `LinuxPerfAsmProfiler` shipped along with JMH to profile generated assembly.

I simply run this

```java
@Benchmark
public Object measureInit() {
  return new ConcurrentReferenceHashMap<>();
}
```

Benchmarking on JDK 8 allows to identify one of non-obvious hot spots:

```
  0.61%        0x00007f32d92772ea: lock addl $0x0,(%rsp)     ;*putfield count
                                                             ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment::&lt;init&gt;@11 (line 476)
                                                             ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap::&lt;init&gt;@141 (line 184)
 15.81%        0x00007f32d92772ef: mov    0x60(%r15),%rdx
```

This corresponds unnecessary assignment of default value to a volatile field:

```java
protected final class Segment extends ReentrantLock {
  private volatile int count = 0;
}
```

and `Segment` is in turn instantiated in loop in constructor of `CCRHM`:

```java
public ConcurrentReferenceHashMap(
    int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, int concurrencyLevel, ReferenceType referenceType) {
  this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
  this.shift = calculateShift(concurrencyLevel, MAXIMUM_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL);
  int size = 1 << this.shift;
  this.referenceType = referenceType;
  int roundedUpSegmentCapacity = (int) ((initialCapacity + size - 1L) / size);
  this.segments = (Segment[]) Array.newInstance(Segment.class, size);
  for (int i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
   this.segments[i] = new Segment(roundedUpSegmentCapacity);
  }
}
```

So the instruction is likely to be really hot. Full layout of assembly can be found in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/stsypanov/ff5678987c6f95a2aaf292fa2a3b92a8)

Then I run the same benchmark on JDK 14 and again use `LinuxPerfAsmProfiler`, but now I don't have any explicit pointing to `volatile int count = 0` [in captured assembly](https://gist.github.com/stsypanov/2e4bd73c39d7465cbdd75ba26d4bc217).

Looking for `lock addl $0x0` instruction which is assignment of `0` under `lock` prefix I have found this:

```
  0.08%                          │  0x00007f3717d46187:   lock addl $0x0,-0x40(%rsp)
 23.74%                          │  0x00007f3717d4618d:   mov    0x120(%r15),%rbx
```

which is likely to correspond `volatile int count = 0` because it follows constructor call of `Segment`'s superclass `ReentrantLock`:

```
  0.77%                          │  0x00007f3717d46140:   movq   $0x0,0x18(%rax)              ;*new {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                 │                                                            ; - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock::&lt;init&gt;@5 (line 294)
                                 │                                                            ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment::&lt;init&gt;@6 (line 484)
                                 │                                                            ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap::&lt;init&gt;@141 (line 184)
  0.06%                          │  0x00007f3717d46148:   mov    %r8,%rcx
  0.05%                          │  0x00007f3717d4614b:   mov    %rax,%rbx
  0.03%                          │  0x00007f3717d4614e:   shr    $0x3,%rbx
  0.74%                          │  0x00007f3717d46152:   mov    %ebx,0xc(%r8)
  0.06%                          │  0x00007f3717d46156:   mov    %rax,%rbx
  0.05%                          │  0x00007f3717d46159:   xor    %rcx,%rbx
  0.02%                          │  0x00007f3717d4615c:   shr    $0x14,%rbx
  0.72%                          │  0x00007f3717d46160:   test   %rbx,%rbx
                             ╭   │  0x00007f3717d46163:   je     0x00007f3717d4617f
                             │   │  0x00007f3717d46165:   shr    $0x9,%rcx
                             │   │  0x00007f3717d46169:   movabs $0x7f370a872000,%rdi
                             │   │  0x00007f3717d46173:   add    %rcx,%rdi
                             │   │  0x00007f3717d46176:   cmpb   $0x8,(%rdi)
  0.00%                      │   │  0x00007f3717d46179:   jne    0x00007f3717d46509
  0.04%                      ↘   │  0x00007f3717d4617f:   movl   $0x0,0x14(%r8)
  0.08%                          │  0x00007f3717d46187:   lock addl $0x0,-0x40(%rsp)
 23.74%                          │  0x00007f3717d4618d:   mov    0x120(%r15),%rbx
```

The problem is that I don't have any mention of `putfield count` in generated assembly at all.

Could anyone explain why I don't see it?

Comment: Indeed, looks like some JIT optimization broke mapping between compiled code and bci. If run JDK 14 with `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=0`, "putfield count" annotation will become visible again.

Comment: @apangin thanks! Should I then report it to `hotspot-compiler-dev` or `jmh-dev` mailing lists? What do you think?

Comment: That's certainly not a jmh fault. Debug info is missing in `-XX:+PrintAssembly`. So, `hotspot-compiler-dev` will be more appropriate.

Comment: @apangin it looks like this won't be fixed: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2020-August/039513.html

Comment: Yeah, quite expected. I can't agree with the justification though. While it's true that it's hard to maintain the mapping in general, this does not mean it's absolutely impossible in a particular case. Ignoring such problems with no even minimal investigation will eventually end up in no debug info at all.

Comment: @apangin btw, can this flag `-XX:MaxInlineLevel=0` distort the profile in the way that with disabled inlining some other optimizations can be disabled as well? And if it can, do you know any examples of such behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't disable other optimizations directly, but definitely makes them less efficient, as the scope where optimizations can be applied gets notably reduced. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52468276/3448419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that you couldn't use hsdis built for e.g. JDK 8 with JDK 11. For the perfect match you need to build hsdis from JDK sources, then build the JDK itself and run the application on this ad-hoc build.

This approach worked perfectly for me when I was investigating [Missing bounds checking elimination in String constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272651/missing-bounds-checking-elimination-in-string-constructor/70296859).